# Filter out empty Map from a Seq[Map]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, maps, seq

I have this Seq[Map[String,String]] :

```
Seq(Map("Name"-> "Laura", "City" -> "Paris"), Map("Country" -> "Italy"), Map())
```

I want to remove the empty Map so I can obtain:

```
Seq(Map("Name"-> "Laura", "City" -> "Paris"), Map("Country" -> "Italy"))
```

How do I do that please?

Comment: What did you tried? I recommend you to check the **Scaladoc**.

Comment: check answer below that helped me find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val data = Seq(Map("Name"-> "Laura", "City" -> "Paris"), Map("Country" -> "Italy"), Map())

val dataWithoutEmptyMaps = data.filter(_.nonEmpty)
```